# Closing Web-browser from WinRT app (c#)

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

Is there a way to close a browser from my WinRT app? (C#)

**Why I want that?**
I have a web-page that redirects to my app when I open it.
the app indeed opens (by protocol activation) but I want to close the browser since there is no use for it. 
Is there a way? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There used to be a way when there was a supported method called `ApplicationView.TryUnSnap()`. But that method is no longer supported. I mean, it's now `deprecated`:

```
// Deprecated:
//     TryUnsnap may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Apps
//     can be continuously resized, but cannot be snapped, starting in Windows 8.1.
//     Also, ApplicationView static methods may be altered or unavailable for releases
//     after Windows 8.1. Use ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView to get an instance
//     of ApplicationView.
```

Once your app invokes a launcher, it hands off control from the app to the whatever handles the launchers action. In this case, you are using `LaunchUri()` which hands off to whatever handles the `http:` protocol on your system. Usually this is Internet Explorer.

Sorry for the superfluous explanation there. The quick answer is no.

Best of luck!